# What do a House, a Garden, and a River all have in Common?

Tags: word, english, language

What do a **house**, a **garden**, and a **river** all have in common?

The answer should be clear, as you think on it every night.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This seems very likely to be closed as too broad - for instance, they all have the letter "e", though I doubt that's what you're looking for. I recommend trying to narrow it down some.

Comment: Agreed, this is far too broad as there are many different possibilities which are all equally 'correct'. Please [edit] your question so that there's only one correct solution.

Comment: I follow what you guys are saying. It's just a kid's riddle I know from growing up. I wouldn't know how to modify it. I suppose I could try to think of one. LOL!

Comment: @Deusovi I made a change that makes it a little less broad. Let me know if that's better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They all have

> beds. Sleeping beds, garden beds, and river beds.

$\vphantom{And a bunch more filler chars down here.}$